# How to exclude navbar from my login page in yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to remove the navbar from my login page in yii2. Below is the image attached to it. Can anyone tell me how to exclude the navbar from this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a different layout for your login  .. (without the navbar)  .. you can see the layouts in views/layouts ..

and you can change tle layout used  for a view directly in the related action  eg:

```
 public function actioLogin(){


  ...
  .....
  $this->layout = 'your_layout_without_navbar';

  return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);

   }
```